# Power BI report server

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Good Morning,
we have Power BI report server installed on Azure VM. dashboards in the report server throws following error when trying to access/open it.

```
Something went wrong
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
undefined: 
Request ID: 59b0544d-6cd7-abfe-9fd9-d39fbd4f0a9c
Status code: 500
Time: Tue Sep 12 2023 09:29:22 
Service version: /powerbi/libs
```

could you please help me. TIA

P.S. report server has been restarted and checked for updates. there has been no changes to the server or the reports and dashboards. both report server and Power BI desktop used are of version from May 2023.

Comment: Will you be able  to go into the log directory and read the logs.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Report Server\LogFiles

Comment: yes, checked the log files. thanks

Comment: there was a version compatibility issues. took down reports from RS completely and re uploaded them because saving it by overwriting didnt work.

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your log files in the VM. Logs are in below directory

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Report Server\LogFiles`

There can be some compatibility issues and server is not working properly due to that.